# How to search a Table using SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI on iOS and iPadOS 15, we can add a search bar to filter a list using the `searchable` modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @State private var searchTerm = ""
    @State private var selection = Set<Video.ID>()

    private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Video>

    private var searchResults: [Video] {
        if searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return fetchRequest.wrappedValue.filter { _ in true }
        } else {
            return fetchRequest.wrappedValue.filter { $0.matching(searchTerm) }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(searchResults) { item in
                    VideoListCellView(video: item)
                }
            }.searchable(text: $searchTerm, prompt: "Video name") // <-- HERE
        }
    }

}
```

However, on macOS, the `searchable` modifier is not supported in the new `Table` container:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.addDate, order: .reverse)], animation: .default)
    private var videos: FetchedResults<Video>

    @State
    private var selection = Set<Video.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Table(videos, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $videos.sortDescriptors) {
                TableColumn("Title") {
                    Text($0.title)
                }

                TableColumn("Added") {
                    Text($0.addDate)
                }.width(120)

                TableColumn("Published") {
                    Text($0.publishedAt)
                }.width(120)

                TableColumn("Duration") {
                    Text($0.duration)
                }.width(50)
            }.searchable(text: $searchTerm, prompt: "Video name") // <-- GENERATES ERROR
        }
    }

}
```

Trying to use it generates a compile error in the `var body: some View`:

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

Is there another way to search a `Table` on macOS, or is this feature not supported yet?

Comment: Have you tried applying the `searchable` modifier to the NavigationView instead of the table? That might be regarded by SwiftUI's compiler as less complex, and should present the search bar in the same place (the trailing edge of the window toolbar)

Comment: according to Apple docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/searchable(_:text:placement:suggestions:)-7g7oo  `searchable` is supported on macOS 12+.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the `.searchable` modifier to the `NavigationView` instead of the `Table`, as Scott suggested:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.addDate, order: .reverse)], animation: .default)
    private var videos: FetchedResults<Video>

    @State private var selection = Set<Video.ID>()
    @State private var searchTerm = ""

    private var searchResults: [Video] {
        if searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return videos.filter { _ in true }
        } else {
            return videos.filter { $0.matching(searchTerm) }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Table(searchResults, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $videos.sortDescriptors) {
                TableColumn("Title", value: \.title) {
                    Text($0.title)
                }

                TableColumn("Added", value: \.addDate) {
                    Text($0.addDate)
                }.width(120)

                TableColumn("Published", value: \.publishedAt) {
                    Text($0.publishedAt)
                }.width(120)

                TableColumn("Duration") {
                    Text($0.duration)
                }.width(50)
            }
        }.searchable(text: $searchTerm, prompt: "Video name") // <-- HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually managed to get this solution to work today when I placed `.searchable`  directly on the `Table`

Comment: I tested a Table with .searchable modifier. It compiles, but is not needed to get search working.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by updating the predicate of the fetch request using a specific Binding variable.

The below solution is based on an example from the 2021 WWDC video [Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/) where it was used on a List which is what I also used it for but I tested it on one of my tables and it works equally well.

```
@State private var searchText: String = ""
var query: Binding<String> {
    Binding {
        searchText
    } set: { newValue in
        searchText = newValue
        if newValue.isEmpty {
            videos.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        } else {
            videos.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you use pass this variable to `.searchable`

```
Table(videos, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $videos.sortDescriptors) {
    // ...
}
.searchable(text: query, prompt: "Search instrument")
```

The downside of this solution is that a new fetch request is executed for each typed letter. I tried a quick fix by adding `if newValue.count < 3 { return }` in the `else` of the `query` `set` method and it works but it might be a bad restriction, maybe something more advanced can be implemented by using Combine.